# SQL Select if it has 2 names

Tags: sql, select

I have a Oracle DB with user Numbers in it. Like:

```
Prename    ID   
-------    -------
Tom        u2300   
Tom        xu2300   
Julian     ue2301   
Anet       xue2302
```

I will find all users with the same id "unumber"/"uenumber" AND "xnumber"/"xuenumber".
They must both exists. All users with only u/uenumber or xu/xue are ok.

I need help with the Query.
Thanks alot.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Could you give some more examples and point out your cases where they match or don't match?

Comment: Probably want to break that out in to two columns: `type` and `number`. Then `e,2300`,`xu,2300`,`ue,2301`,`xue,2302`. otherwise you're looking at string parsing.

Comment: Do you have control over schema? might be easier to have two columns: prefix, id, and computed column Id = prefix+id. It would make a lot of logic easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
PRENAME ID      ID2
Anet    xue2302 null
Julian  ue2301  null
Tom     u2300   xu2300
```

If yes, this is the query :

```
SELECT u1."Prename", u1.ID as ID, u2.ID as ID2 
FROM users u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u2 ON u2.ID = concat('x',u1.ID)
WHERE u1.ID LIKE 'u%'
UNION
SELECT u1."Prename", u1.ID as ID, u2.ID as ID2 
FROM users u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u2 ON u2.ID = replace(u1.ID,'x')
WHERE u1.ID LIKE 'x%' AND u2.ID is null
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81bb1/13/0

Answer (score 0):

Just looking for the name? Or the ID, too?

```
SELECT "Prename"
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN ID LIKE 'u%' THEN ID END) u_id
FROM users 
GROUP BY "Prename"
HAVING 
   MIN(CASE WHEN ID LIKE 'x%' THEN SUBSTR(ID,2) END)
 = MIN(CASE WHEN ID LIKE 'u%' THEN ID END)
```

Dieter